# CSSで画像の位置がうまく調整できない

Tags: html, css

現在HTMLで↓のように

```
<body>
<div class="daruma"><div style="position:absolute;top:-20px;left:0px;">
<a href="リンク/"><img src="元の画像" border="0" onMouseOver="this.src='マウスオーバー時画像'" onMouseOut="this.src='マウスアウト時画像'" />
</a>
</div>
```

cssで↓のように

```
.daruma {
position: absolute; z-index: 2;
top: 0px;
left: 90px;
width: 96px;
height: 65px;
}
```

書いて画像リンクをしながらマウスオーバーをし、なおかつ位置を指定したいと思っているのですが、
リンク？の位置とマウスオーバー時の画像がずれてしまっているのか通常の画像しか表示されません。

Comment: jsfiddleで試してみましたが、手元のChromeでは問題なく画像が切り替わりました。 https://jsfiddle.net/jgps0866/ マウスオーバー用の画像URLが間違っている、といったことはないでしょうか？

Comment: 「通常の画像しか表示されません」とあったので上のコメントではその点にのみ触れましたが、位置指定もうまくいっていないということであれば、どういう位置に配置されることを期待しているのかを質問文に追記していただけると助かります。